# Custom Dimension in Google Analytics not showing in my queries

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using a Custom Dimension to send my internal UserId to GA. What we need is to know which users are clicking on this button. But when I try to get reports using the Category and Event for this button click, and I include my dimension on the report, it won't show any result. 
But, if I only request eventCategory or eventLabel, it will show for example 2 hits. Which is weird because I am sending the dimension value with each click event that I am tracking, and seems like I don't have values for this specific event.
How can I make sure I have information in GA for this event?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :-) Please take a moment to read the guidelines on asking questions in the site's Help Center. You don't provide enough information. At the very least, you should include the code you've tried.

Comment: +1 to the above comment: show us the code you're using to send and report on the data. Also, have you enabled the custom dimension in your Google Analytics admin settings?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You need to set custom dimension index on your google analytics console.

Once you login into your google analytics console, go to admin tab.
At bottom of the middle column you can see Custom Definitions.
Click on Custom Dimension under Custom Definitions and define Custom dimension name for your custom dimension index. Default scope is for hit, if you want that for session change the scope.

This is all for V4 version of the analytic.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I do have the dimension created and also it is shown whenever I query other information, but seem like for this specific button it is not getting it. The problem here is that the information I am getting is not accurate, when I query without this Dimension2, I will get results, but if I add the Dimension2 to my query, it won't show any record.

Comment: That means Dimension2 is not being sent to analytics. Some times it might take a day to update. I believe you are already sending custom dimensions this way
`mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()         .setCategory(<eventName>)         .setAction(<actionName>);
        .setCustomDimension(1, <CustomDimensionValue>)         .setCustomDimension(2, <CustomDimensionValue>)         .build());`

Comment: I have Dimension 1 defined, but I am not using it, instead I use Dimension 2, does this could cause any problem? Meaning that I directly send Dimension 2 value only? The weird thing though is that for many other events I do, get the dimension value on the reports :(

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
 GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(YourActivity.this);
        Tracker tracker = analytics.newTracker("TRACKER ID");
        tracker.setScreenName("SCREEN NAME");
        tracker.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder()
                .setCustomDimension(1, "VALUE")
                .setCustomMetric(1,1)
                .build());
```

Here is 1 in custom dimension and custom metric is the index.

Comment: AppViewBuilder is deprecated now